# Notification system/service in C# with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, events, delegates, solid-principles

I need plan for build Notifications/Alerts system.

I have object named "Campaign" and it have "Status". Status can be Accepted, Rejected, Supplement, Work and others. 
I want send Notifications/Alerts when the Status change.

E.q. e-mail notification and alert in my portal.

I don't want make it all in one controller where I operate on Campaign. So I was thinking about Delegates and Events. But in last I don't know enought to do it.

What I thinking about:

Domain model:

```
class Campaign {
    CampaignStatus Status { get;    set;}
}
abstract class Notification { 
    // properties
}
class EmailNotification {
    // properties specific for email
}
class Alert {
    // properties specific for alerts
}
class CampaignAlert {
    // properties specific for campaign alerts 
}

Services:
INotificationsService {
    Send();
}
IAlertsService : INotificationsService {
    Get(); // I need showing list of alerts too
    GetAll();
    Update(); // for updating info if alert was viewed. 
    Save(); // I need saving alerts in db. 
}
```

And how I can do it with events? So much automatic as can. Ofcourse I can manualy call the AlertsService and make alert. But this is bad ;)

I was thinking about adding delegate and event to Campaign.

```
class Campaign {
    public delegate void CampaignStatusChange(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event CampaignStatusChange OnCampaignStatusChange;
}
```

And connect event with:

```
class CampaignStatusChangeHandler {
    public CampaignStatusChangeHandler(IRepository<bla bla> repository, INotificationsService notificationService) {
        // these will be inject via ctor
    }

    // 
}
```

I want made it as much as I can with SOLID, KISS, and DRY. Ofcourse with TDD and I using IoC to inject objects ;)

Summary I need notification service that I can indepentend send emails and alerts. I need display alerts on frontend.

My alert domain model like that:

```
public abstract class Notification
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public NotificationType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum NotificationType
{
    Email,
    Alert
}

public class EmailNotification : Notification
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> To { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> Bcc { get; set; }
}

public class Alert : Notification
{
    public object LinkedObject { get; set; }
    public bool WasSeen { get; set; }
}
public class CampaignAlert : Alert
{
    public CampaignAlertType CampaignAlertType { get; set; }
}
public enum CampaignAlertType
{
    Accepted,
    Rejected,
    Active,
    Finished
}
```

When I want to send Alert to user I want send email sometimes and alert. 
Sometimes I want send only email and only alert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't use delegates and events here. Calling a method is much more transparent and you wouldn't have any benefits of using delegates and events.

My structure would look like that:

```
interface ICampaignService
{
    // It's business logic
    // 1. Updates campaign
    // 2. Creates notification using builder
    // 3. Uses notification sender to send notification
    // (4. creates alert object for notification)
    void UpdateCampaignStatus(int campaignId, Status status);
}

// Builds different notifications based on different
// campaign statuses. For instance assign different 
// email templates and use different text.
interface INotificationBuilder<TNotification> where TNotification : Notification
{
    TNotification Build();
}

interface INotificationSender
{
    Send(Notification notification);
}

interface IAlertsRepository
{
    Get();
    GetAll();
    Update();
    Create();
}
```

Also possible (if there are different types of notifications)

```
// If you want to send different types of notifications like
// Email, Push, SMS etc. Each notification type requires different
// logic for sending notification. Strategy pattern is perfect here.
interface INotificationStrategy : INotificationSender
{
    Send(Notification notification);
}
```

It's all depends on your application extensibility requirements. SOLID is very important, but make sure to avoid over-engineering (you mentioned KISS :)).

Comment: Why Builder and Strategy here?

Comment: @Nerf you may need notification builder to build different notifications based on campaign status (different email templates and/or text). Notification strategy would be useful if you have different types of notifications e.g. email notification, sms, push etc.

Comment: Ok thx. I need read something more about these patterns because I don't see them here.

Comment: @Nerf yes, it would be useful. I was building similar notification engine maybe 6 months ago. Take a look at following patterns: `Strategy`, `Builder`, `Abstract factory`, `Factory method` (it's from GoF). You may also want to read about `State Machine` approach.

Comment: There is problem. How in Builder I can manage scenario with different properties in each notification email and alert? In email I have title, content and to. In Alert I have "Linked Object" it details about campaign and WasSeen boolean flag. The builder is for builder same object but with different behaviour?

Comment: @Nerf please see my updated notification builder. For simplicity you can use builder inside NotificationStrategy to make sure correct builder is used for notification type.

Comment: Can u make more explained example?

Comment: @Andrei can you please explain your example a little bit more? I got stuck on the same step like Nerf...

Comment: @fen89 it's a matter of taste. In my example you should extend INotificationBuilder to implement concrete notification builders, for instance EmailNotificationBuilder or ResetPasswordNotificationBuilder, depending on the problem you are trying to solve.